# Find whether dictionary is simple key-value pair or nested dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I've two dictionaries one with simple key-value pair and another one which is a collection of nested dictionaries.

Simple Dict:

```
{
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2",
   "key3" : "value3"
}
```

Nested Dict:

```
{
  "key1" : {
      "key2" : "value2",
      "key3" : "value3",
      "key4" : "value4"
      }
  "key5" : {
      "key6": "value6",
      "key7" : "value7"
      }
 }
```

I want to find whether the dict is simple or nested, how can I do the same?

Comment: loop and check the values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just loop on all the values within the dict, and check if any of them is a dict:

```
>>> d = {
...   "key1" : {
...       "key2" : "value2",
...       "key3" : "value3",
...       "key4" : "value4"
...       },
...   "key5" : {
...       "key6": "value6",
...       "key7" : "value7"
...       }
...  }
>>> any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in d.values())
True
```

The `any` in code above will enable short circuiting of the checks.

For a simple non-nested dictionary, the same check returns False:

```
>>> d = {"key2" : "value2",
... "key3" : "value3",
... "key4" : "value4"}
>>> any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in d.values())
False
```